# Can I set ng-change on {{data| currency}}?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code and would like to set ng-change to a model being set with {{}}. I dont want the textbox, but the code works with that. Can I do that?

```
<td ng-repeat="period in vm.Grid">
    <div ng-model="period.Value" contenteditable="true" ng-change="vm.updateValue(period)">
        {{ period.Value | currency  }}
        //if I use on a text box (see below), the ng-change works
        <input ng-model ="period.Value" ng-change="vm.updateManualValue(period)"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Since you don't want the textbox, the view won't probably change `period.Value` so putting a `$watch` on for `period.Value` should do the trick. But `$watch`ing a lot of value is computationally expensive so be careful.

Comment: So {{period.Value | currency}} is for display only?

Comment: That is correct. In other words, the expression creates one-way binding with period.Value which has been formatted with the currency filter.

Comment: ngChange is specifically for view changes to the model.  You said the view can't change this model so your choices are to either use a $watch as mentioned above or go to what can actually change this value and hook into for your change event.